# Saving a row and posting to same page via php

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, html, json

I am stuck with this.. and I am new also so not really promising. I have a html table that is being populated using php and mysql. Each row has 4 columns, one of the columns is a 'update' button with the follwoing syntax

```
print("<input type='submit' value='Update' name='update' class='submit_button'/>");
```

now, the class='submit_button' is new as i added per a suggestion in a related question using json and the function is here

```
$( '.submit_button' ).click( function(){

        var value = {};

        $( this ).closest( '.submit_button' ).find( 'input, select' ).each(function(){  
            value[ $(this).attr('name') ] = $(this).val();
        });

        $.post( "test.php", 
            value,
            function(data){
                //success
                alert( data );
            }, 
            "json"
        );

    });
```

I was expecting to see the alert saying it posted or something... but nothing... Now I also tried adding a form to the row.. but that did not work either. Here is my full html table

```
print("<table id='results'><tr><th>ID</th><th>Image</th><th>Name</th><th>Price</th><th>Price Label</th><th>Description</th><th>Update</th></tr>");

     while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array( $result2 )){ 
         $client_id = $row2["client_id"];
         $client_name = $row2["client_name"];
         $client_disc = $row2["client_disc"];
         $client_price = $row2["client_price"];
         $client_image = $row2["client_image"];
         $client_price_label = $row2["client_price_label"];

         print("<tr>");   
         print("<td>");
         print("<p style='font-size:14px; color:blue; padding:0;'>$client_id</p>");
         print("</td>");          
         print("<td>");
         print("<img class='custom_rate' alt='' src='$client_image' />");
         print("</td>");
         print("<td width='100px'>");
         print("<input type='text' value='$client_name' name='clientname'/>");
         print("</td>");
         print("<td>");
         print("<input type='text' value='$client_price' name='clientprice'/>");
         print("</td>");
         print("<td width='100px'>");
         print("<input type='text' value='$client_price_label' name='clientpricelabel'/>");
         print("</td>");
         print("<td width='100px'>");
         print("<textarea cols='15' rows='2' name='description'>$client_desc</textarea>");
         print("</td>");
         print("<td width='100px'>");
         print("<input type='submit' value='Update' name='update'/>");
         print("</td>");
         print("</tr>");
    }

    print("</table>");
```

So i am not sure how to make this work, if you could help me elaborate on the json way.. or if there is another way... I was thinking maybe something simpler.. How can I just click on the update button and get the values and store them somewhere in the same page where i can use them, and then i will pass those values to php variables and do my update?

Thank you for the patience

Comment: Why are you using all those print statements instead of just the <? .. ?> syntax? It's damn slow no to do so, you know ;) . And to be honest, your code just leaves me hanging with a dozen questions.

Comment: I can answer one of then :) i am new to PHP and all the stuff lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a submit button so it is submitting your page before the Javascript has a chance to run.

Try a regular type="button" and see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

Also try `return false;` before closing the function;